# Is this how I make a linked list within a linked list?

Tags: c, types, struct, linked-list

Well my project requires me for make a link list within a link list. Is it ok for me to define it this way?

```
struct users {
  int user_ID;

  struct playlist{
    int album;
    int track_num;
    struct playlist *next;
  }

  struct users *next;
};
```

Comment: i think that's it... is there any problems or errors?

Comment: Seems reasonable. Get on with the code - might get sometime to enjoy the weekend!

Comment: There apperas to be a name + semicolon missing after the `struct playlist { ...}`

Comment: there is no difference to whether or not you put "struct playlist" in or outside of the other struct in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not separate the structures?

```
struct Playlist{
    int album;
    int track_num;
    struct Playlist *next;
}


struct users {
  int user_ID;

  struct Playlist playlist 
  struct users *next;
};
```

it makes it easier to read, and easier to comprehend.

Comment: does the upper case P in playlist matter?

Comment: nope, its just a way of telling the struct-name and the variable name appart.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's absolutely fine to have `struct` members in `struct`s, which is what you're doing.

Some find it nice to abstract out the "linked list" data, and just instantiate that whenever needed, but doing so might involve a need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a linked list is a set of structs which have pointers to each other, so your solution is valid.

Point of order: when working with linked lists, it's really easy to fat-finger the code, or to forget a line, so write a set of functions/macros to do the list manipulation and always call those, so that you only have to get it right *once*.